# Confusion on Python Classes in Pyxhook source code

Tags: python, class, open-source

I'm currently working with a library in Python that records all user input. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook/blob/master/pyxhook.py

I've taken a look at the source for a while and can't figure out how it's actually working. I traced the function `processevents(self, reply)` throughout the entire source and don't understand where the vairble `event` is coming from. The exact lines are:

```
def processevents(self, reply):
        if reply.category != record.FromServer:
            return
        if reply.client_swapped:
            print("* received swapped protocol data, cowardly ignored")
            return
        try:
            # Get int value, python2.
            intval = ord(reply.data[0])
        except TypeError:
            # Already bytes/ints, python3.
            intval = reply.data[0]
        if (not reply.data) or (intval < 2):
            # not an event
            return
        data = reply.data
        while len(data):
            event, data = rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(
                data,
                self.record_dpy.display,
                None,
                None
            )
            if event.type == X.KeyPress:
                hookevent = self.keypressevent(event)
                self.KeyDown(hookevent)
            elif event.type == X.KeyRelease:
                hookevent = self.keyreleaseevent(event)
                self.KeyUp(hookevent)
            elif event.type == X.ButtonPress:
                hookevent = self.buttonpressevent(event)
                self.MouseAllButtonsDown(hookevent)
            elif event.type == X.ButtonRelease:
                hookevent = self.buttonreleaseevent(event)
                self.MouseAllButtonsUp(hookevent)
            elif event.type == X.MotionNotify:
                # use mouse moves to record mouse position, since press and
                # release events do not give mouse position info
                # (event.root_x and event.root_y have bogus info).
                hookevent = self.mousemoveevent(event)
                self.MouseMovement(hookevent)

        # print("processing events...", event.type)
```

Comment: The function rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value() is returning an event object that has type as an attribute within it.It also returns data.So,for each keypress or buttonpress an event object is created

Comment: I'm not familiar with that function, where is it even coming from?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that these events are being emitted by the operating system, and not really anything to do with Python. They are being captured and enumerated by the Xlib [python interface](https://github.com/python-xlib).

Comment: It's coming from Xlib, in particular from this file: https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/master/Xlib/protocol/rq.py   the EventField object is parsing the data in `reply`

Answer (score 1):

In the code shown by you,an event object is created dynamically for each keypress or buttonpress.
In the operating system,when click on any keyboard character,automatically an event is trigerred that says this particular key was pressed.

`event, data = rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(
                data,
                self.record_dpy.display,
                None,
                None
            )`
Here,as soon as the user has pressed a key,a request is sent to the server and the event is further sent for processing to this function with the event attribute as type.
So,comparing type of the event whether it's keypress or buttonpress etc..the code is doing further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source code:

```
class EventField(ValueField):
    structcode = None

    def pack_value(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, Event):
            raise BadDataError('%s is not an Event for field %s' % (value, self.name))

        return value._binary, None, None

    def parse_binary_value(self, data, display, length, format):
        from . import event

        estruct = display.event_classes.get(byte2int(data) & 0x7f, event.AnyEvent)
        if type(estruct) == dict:
            # this etype refers to a set of sub-events with individual subcodes
            estruct = estruct[indexbytes(data, 1)]

        return estruct(display = display, binarydata = data[:32]), data[32:]
```

`parse_binary_value` returns two values, the former of which is assigned to the `event` variable.

You can see the greater context for this source code [here](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/eb3f4b70671afa09cdd38b43d7cb5e38d92f63a7/Xlib/protocol/rq.py)